# C++ is blowing my mind

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 int x = 1;
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i);
  // What will the next line do? Increment???????????/
  ++x;
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Why does the code print 1 and not 2?

Comment: Wait a second, you copied code verbatim from an article which *explains* this behavior (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/086.htm), and then you ask us why this behavior occurs? How about reading the article you took the code from?

Comment: @user7181146 : Did you copy the code from that gotw article or did somebody asked you this?

Comment: Some compilers have trigraphs disabled by default...

Comment: @jalf a friend of mine asked this puzzle.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [trigraph sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) `??/` sequence is converted to `'\'` so `++x` is a part of the comment line.

This [gotw article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/086.htm) discusses the same problem[exact same code].

Comment: Just for completeness sake, i think this first appeared here: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/086.htm

Comment: Weren't trigraphs obsoleted some time ago? At least in gcc? Anyway +1 for an sharp eye ;-)

Comment: Ah clever, I usually just assume that comments like these are added when posting the question, for the sake of clarifying where the surprising behavior is seen

Comment: Well spotted! It looks like the OP did this deliberately.

Comment: GCC (at least the version used by codepad.org) will point at it and generate an error, both for the trigraph itself and the multi-line comment: http://codepad.org/BEo122JQ

Comment: GCC actually does not support trigraphs without the -trigraphs flag.